# Добавление картинки фрейм Java

Tags: java, изображения

Здравствуйте! У меня возник вопрос по поводу добавления картинки в JFrame. Мне нужно добавить картинку и иметь возможность менять ее координаты. Код ниже. Не корректно работает смена координат(setLocation,setBounds) этого лейбла,в котором лежит картинка. Хотел бы узнать как исправить,спасибо.

## [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
package gui;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.IOException;


public class GameGUI extends JFrame{
    public GameGUI() throws IOException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GetFruit");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        JLabel l1 = new JLabel();
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(GameGUI.class.getResource("p.jpg"));
        l1.setIcon(icon);
        frame.add(l1).setBounds(100,100,120,200);

    }
}
```

Comment: Добавте код как текст вместо картинки.

Comment: @mrKott Покажи попытки других реализаций. Вопрос не корректный.

Comment: @Владимир изменил. Мне нужно исправить,чтобы я мог задавать координаты изображению,и чтобы все работало корректно.